# How to show QAbstractTableModel's status in a QStatusBar?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4, qt4.7

I have my custom implementation of QAbstractTableModel and of QSortFilterProxyModel, used for filtering. The table is shown in a QTableView.

The parent dialog of my QTableView has a QStatusBar, with a read-only QLineEdit widget.

In my overriding data() method of QAbstractTableModel, I'm setting the pertinent values for the Qt::StatusTipRole role.

Now I'm missing part of the plumbing: how do I get my per-cell StatusTipRole data to show up in my widget inside QStatusBar?

Comment: Assuming you want the QStatusBar to update on mouse click, you can connect QTableView's inherited signal [`clicked`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#clicked) to a function that gets the text and calls QStatusBar::setText() accordingly

Comment: The idea is to update the status bar based on which cell the mouse is hovering over. I've managed to get this behavior by having a slot for the mouseMoveEvent signal of the TableView, but that fails when filtering is involved, and I have no access to the model data at that point.

Comment: [This thread](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/50677-Problem-with-QTableView-and-QSortFilterProxyModel) has a discussion on that matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to override the view widget. Qt provides built-in support to show status tips for items in a model.

Normally, You just need to return a `QString` from your model's [`data()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) when `role` is [`QStatusTipRole`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum), and that `QString` will be shown in the status bar when you hover your item.

You also need to turn on [mouse tracking](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop) for the `QTableView` so that you get status bar updates without the mouse button being pressed. This is because when mouse tracking is disabled (by default), the widget receives mouse move events only while a mouse button is pressed.

Now, in order to display those status tips in your `QLineEdit` instead of the default status bar, You can override your main window's [`event`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#event) function, intercept `QStatusTipEvent`s, and show tips in your `QLineEdit`.

Here is an example implementation:

[image: screenshot]

```
#include <QtWidgets>

//model to provide dummy data
class MyModel : public QAbstractTableModel{
public:
    explicit MyModel(QObject* parent= nullptr):QAbstractTableModel(parent){}
    ~MyModel() = default;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const{
        if(parent.isValid()) return 0;
        return 4;
    }
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const{
        if(parent.isValid()) return 0;
        return 20;
    }
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const{
        QVariant val;
        switch(role){
        case Qt::DisplayRole: case Qt::EditRole:
            val= QString("Display (%1, %2)")
                    .arg(index.row(), 2, 10, QChar('0'))
                    .arg(index.column(), 2, 10, QChar('0'));
            break;
        case Qt::ToolTipRole:
            val= QString("Tooltip (%1, %2)")
                    .arg(index.row(), 2, 10, QChar('0'))
                    .arg(index.column(), 2, 10, QChar('0'));
            break;
        case Qt::StatusTipRole:
            val= QString("StatusTip (%1, %2)")
                    .arg(index.row(), 2, 10, QChar('0'))
                    .arg(index.column(), 2, 10, QChar('0'));
            break;

        }
        return val;
    }
};


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget* parent= nullptr):QMainWindow(parent){
        //set up GUI
        layout.addWidget(&lineEditFilter);
        layout.addWidget(&tableView);
        setCentralWidget(&cw);
        lineEditStatusBar.setReadOnly(true);
        statusBar()->addPermanentWidget(&lineEditStatusBar);

        //set up models
        filterModel.setSourceModel(&model);
        tableView.setModel(&filterModel);
        connect(&lineEditFilter, &QLineEdit::textChanged, this, &MainWindow::updateFilter);

        //turn on mouse tracking for the table view
        tableView.setMouseTracking(true);

    }
    ~MainWindow()= default;

    Q_SLOT void updateFilter(const QString& text){
        filterModel.setFilterFixedString(text);
    }
protected:

    //in order to intercept QStatusTipEvents
    //and show tips in the line edit instead of the normal status bar
    bool event(QEvent *event){
        if(event->type() != QEvent::StatusTip) return QMainWindow::event(event);
        QStatusTipEvent* statusTipEvent= static_cast<QStatusTipEvent*>(event);
        lineEditStatusBar.setText(statusTipEvent->tip());
        statusTipEvent->ignore();
        return true;
    }

private:
    QWidget cw;
    QVBoxLayout layout{&cw};
    QLineEdit lineEditFilter;
    QTableView tableView;
    MyModel model;
    QSortFilterProxyModel filterModel;
    QLineEdit lineEditStatusBar;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow mw;
    mw.show();


    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example - this is exactly what I was looking for. After playing around with your sample code, I realized that my main dialog is a QDialog, and not a QMainWindow. It's out of my control to change that, so I'm listening to mouse events and calling model->data() by hand, which is unfortunate.

Comment: @jehuty , You can still use the same approach with a `QDialog` subclass. If I understood your problem right, [here](http://pastebin.com/Dd55dzsB) is the same example after modifying `MainWindow` to become a `QDialog` subclass.

Comment: "You also need to turn on mouse tracking...". Thank you!